# Why table inside swiper.js not working on mobile?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I created swiper with swiper.js and in one of tabs I put normal HTML table. When I open my swiper on mobile, I cant move table to last record. I mean, cursor/finger swipe in horizontal directions. it's worth pointing out, it moves correctly with shift + mouse scroll on table. I When i open swiper on desktop, and next minimize it to mobile, it works correctly. What went wrong?

swiper initialization:

```
const sliderContainer = this.tabsContainer.find('.swiper-container')[0];

    this.slider = new Swiper(sliderContainer, {
        simulateTouch: true,
        touchRatio: 0,
        initialSlide: 0,
        spaceBetween: 0,
        slidesPerView: 1,
        roundLengths: true,
        effect: 'fade',
        autoHeight: true,
        noSwiping: false,
        normalizeSlideIndex: true,
        slideToClickedSlide: true,
        allowTouchMove: false
    });
```

Comment: "allowTouchMove - If false, then the only way to switch the slide is use of external API functions like slidePrev or slideNext", I don't know much about slider.js but it sounds like setting that parameter to true might fix your issue. [Taken from their documentation](https://swiperjs.com/api/#parameters#allowTouchMove) you'll have to scroll down to find it

Comment: allowTouchMove: true not working :/